# How to extract arrays from a multidimensional arrays

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

I have a multidimensional array below. I want to individually extract each of the arrays so that I can then do something with each of the array.

there is plenty of material on how to extract values from a multidimensional array but nothing on how to extract an array from a multidimensional array.

```
array (size=13)

  'languages' => 
    array (size=1)
      'lang' => string '1' (length=1)
  'Jobs' => 
    array (size=1)
      'job' => 
        array (size=4)
          0 => string '1' (length=1)
          1 => string '2' (length=1)
          2 => string '3' (length=1)
          3 => string '4' (length=1)
  'Skills' => 
    array (size=1)
      'name' => 
        array (size=5)
          0 => string '1' (length=1)
          1 => string '2' (length=1)
          2 => string '3' (length=1)
          3 => string '4' (length=1)
          4 => string '5' (length=1)
```

Comment: An array in a multi-dimensional array is nothing but another value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a variable that references a particular key in the array

```
$job = $myArray['Jobs']['job'];
```